# Adding and removing v4l2-loopback devices?

Tags: lxc, v4l, v4l2loopback

I have different lxc containers running on my machine and a webcam is also attached. I want all of the lxc containers to access this camera. I came across 'v4l2-loopback' devices and found a way to add devices using;

```
modprobe v4l2loopback devices=3
```

And I directed the stream from /dev/video0 to the desired virtual video devices.
My question is how to add and remove these v4l2loopback devices at runtime? I want to add/remove a device whenever any lxc container is launched/deleted. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I don't have an elegant way to remove these devices other than force remove the v4l2loopback module:

```
sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback
```

Comment: After I run this command it gives me no output. I dont know if it removed anything....

Comment: You can use `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` to check your virtual devices

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the full up to date v4l2loopback driver from https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback, then you can use the `v4l2loopback-ctl` utility to add and remove devices while the module is installed using the command `v4l2loopback-ctl add /dev/video2` and `v4l2loopback-ctl delete /dev/video2`.

Unfortunately, this is not the version that is currently in Debian, which is a mishmash of an old version and some code from the current version, and is still using the old (pre 2021) `v4l2loopback-ctl` and the driver with no dynamic device management.

Comment: Will reinstallation on older OS Debian flavors use the new version if reinstalled? I am getting errors trying to use that code on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: For runtime device control you need v4l2loopback version 0.13 or higher. Ubuntu 22.04 still has v4l2loopback 0.12 that has the old v4l2loopback-ctl that doesn't support adding and removing devices in runtime. **There are currently no Ubuntu versions that ship v4l2loopback version 0.13**, not even the next version currently in development. The *only* Linux OS shipping v4l2loopback version 0.13 - to the best of my knowledge - is Debian Sid.

Comment: It is easy to check if you have the correct version - run `v4l2loopback-ctl --version` . If it says "0.6", then you have the old version and that will not let you add and remove devices in runtime. You need a version that says 0.13.0 or higher.

Comment: thanks! at the moment, I just use `modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=${videoDevIdNum} card_label="${cardLabel}` and to remove `modprobe -r v4l2loopback`. correct? I add a specific one and then remove all from the app, in run time, seems to work ok at the terminal, and yes, I have 0.6

Comment: That seems like it should work.